# Safely insert data on SQLite database

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

I need to load a data coming from a service in a table on the SplashScreenActivity. I've followed [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) tutorial and everything works just fine. I have also added a custom AsyncTask to run the insert loop in the background.

**The problem is that if a configuration change happens in the middle of the insert (e.g. screen rotation) everything blows up and I get corrupted data saved on the database.**

I've read stuff about CursorLoader but that's only for querying the database. I've also looked at ContentProviders but they don't solve the problem.

**Any ideas on how to handle this problem?**

### What I basically need is:

1. *Access database from a background thread to keep the UI responsive.*
2. *Handle configuration changes when doing inserts on the database.*

UPDATE:

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    ...

    // Create a Volley Request and fetch data
}
```

When I get the Response object I start the AsyncTask:

```
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        if (response.optString("lastrunstatus").equals(
                "success")) {

            JSONObject results = response
                    .optJSONObject("results");
            JSONArray objects = results
                    .optJSONArray("objects");

            new HandleResponseAsyncTask().execute(objects);
        }
    }
```

In the AsyntTask, I insert all objects:

```
    private class HandleResponseAsyncTask extends
        AsyncTask<JSONArray, String, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mDataSource.open();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(JSONArray... params) {
        publishProgress("Deleting data...");
        mProductosDataSource.deleteAll();

        publishProgress("Saving data...");
        JSONArray objects = params[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = objects.optJSONObject(i);
            // Get each column value from JSON
            ...
            mDataSource.insert(id, name, description);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... messages) {
        mTextViewLoading.setText(messages[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        mDataSource.close();

        // Go to main
        startMainActivity();
    }
}
```

NOTE: mDataSource holds an instance of a helper class that calls the methods in my custom SQLiteOpenHelper class.

Comment: Perhaps you should post some code to give us an idea what you are currently doing, but my first thought is to let the Service add the data to the database since it won't be destroyed by a configuration change.

Comment: As for the little information you provided, I can only suggest you to use a **transaction**. The data will be inserted **all or nothing**. So, you'll **prevent data corruption**.

Comment: @Karakuri / Der Golem I've just posted come code.

Comment: Begin a transaction before your insert loop. Enclose the loop in a try/catch/finally block. In the try part, after the loop set the transaction as successful. In the finally part, close the transaction